# Removing distant vertices/keeping close vertices

Tags: vertices

I have a very large map of vertices imported into blender[image]

I want to keep the areas where there are many vertices close together but remove all the random dots here and there. I couldn't find any other post about removing vertices based on distance and thought there could be some function or program to do this. If not can python interact with the vertices and remove them based on distances to nearby vertices?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set.   See https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html

Comment: Yes, I've [uploaded the whole .obj](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkhIzPZ8IzvRpZ0HP-VKTT7PAdpANA?e=Mhtl02) with a huge list of vertices.